# Dynamic method invocation trace logging in JVM

Tags: java, trace, method-invocation

I want to analysis a large open-sourced java framework. 
In order to do so, I want to log the method invocation sequences during its execution.
The output should include multiple entries, each entry contains "method name, call time, exit time".
It's hard to modify the source code of the original framework to enable this tracing task.
I hope to find some profiliers or approaches. Thanks!

Comment: I would use a profiler e.g. FlightRecorder. to see how much time is spent in each method.

Comment: no, thanks. I don't need that information. I need the method calling sequence (i.e., trace).

Comment: Do you mean like debugging the code gives you, but as a log.

Comment: I just want to log the sequence of methods being executed. This can be achieved by adding a ``system.out.println()" at the first line of every method, but it's too stupid to do so as the framework may call more than thousands of methods, I want to have a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a useful tool myself @ https://code.google.com/archive/p/javashot/, although I haven't tried it out yet. 
Any more suggestions are still welcome!